# Android security for images

Tags: java, android, encryption, obfuscation, android-security

I am developing an app which is a graphical book. Every week, a new chapter is being released and the app will be updated. There are basically images that are going to be shown to the user as slides. The user can subscribe and all chapters will be visible to the user (the image sources are offline and embedded inside the APK file). The images are not saved into the internal SD card (like they are not shown in the phone gallery after installing the app).

I am afraid that it is not a safe way to show the content to the users. What if someone just extracts all the images?  I am thinking of the solutions below. Please give me the best option to keep my image files secured.

1. Obfuscating the app (I'm not sure if this works in this case. I know obfuscating helps to change the codes but I'm not sure if it helps to encrypt the images)
2. Using an online server and let subscribed users download the images (I think this way it might be saved inside the external storage. Anyway after the download the images must be available offline)
3. Should I encrypt the images by an encryption method?

Answer (score 0):

Let's explore your options one by one

1. If you obfuscate the app, it can be deobfuscated
2. If you use an online server, the images will be downloaded, you can manage to store the downloaded images into the memory instead of the disk and then show directly from memory.
3. If you encrypt the images, you need to have some decryption method/key implemented in the app, which can be retrieved and bingo,
   the user can have decrypted images.

So if downloading the images from an online service will not break your business requirement, then go ahead with that.
Remember that, in any of the cases, if one is determined to save the images, he/she can.

You may need to have multiple methods in place to make it harder for those, seeking to save it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even after the downloading, they should be available offline to the users. What is the difference of downloading them and putting them from the beginning inside the app? If the phone is rooted, can't they just access the images?